# Spark Streaming Run Actions On DStream Asynchronously

Tags: apache-spark, asynchronous, spark-streaming, dstream

I'm writing a program for data ingestion. Read from Kafka to DStream split the Dstrem to 3 streams and executing Actions on each one:

```
val stream = createSparkStream(Globals.configs, ssc)
val s1 = stream.filter(<predicat1>)
val s2 = stream.filter(<predicat2>)
val s3 = stream.filter(<predicat3>)

//I'm looking for something like:
s1.forEachRddAsync(...
s2.forEachRddAsync(...
s3.forEachRddAsync(...
```

If it possible to trigger async submit on whole DStream and not RDD.

Answer (score 0):

`DStream` action methods, while indeed blocking, don't process data. These only register `DStream` as an output stream.

Once the `StreamingContext` is started, the processing will be scheduled according to the available resources, and if these allow, be processed without limiting each other.

Comment: From what I see in spark UI, all foreachRdd actions run sequentially